# How to convert LINQ query data to WPF/MVVM List

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, entity-framework-6, devexpress-wpf

I have two entities:

```
 public class Transport
    {
        [Key]
        public int TransportID {get; set;}
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
    }
    public class TransportOwner
    {
        [Key]
        public int TransportOwnerID {get; set;}
        public int OwnerID {get; set;}
        public int TransportID {get; set;}
        [ForeignKey("TransportID")]
        public virtual Transport Transport { get; set; }
    }
```

In ViewModel I created two lists from these two entities:

```
public List<Transport> TransportList 
public List<OwnerTransport> OwnerTransportList
```

And I need to construct third list for my WPF/MVVM form with data from these two lists:
Structure I need is:

```
OwnerTransportID
OwnerID
TransportID
Model
Brand
```

What do I do next in my ViewModel.cs? Do I need to create new class?

```
public class OwnerTransportTransport
{
    [Key]
    public int OwnerTransportID {get; set;}
    public int TransportID {get; set;}
    public string OwnerID {get; set;}
    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Brand { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
List<OwnerTransport> OwnerTransportTransportList
```

?? Could You help?

Data I get from linq query:

```
var ownerTransportList = OwnerTransport.Select(t => new
{
    t.OwnerTransportID,
    t.OwnerID,
    t.TransportID,
    ModelName = t.Transport.ModelName,
    BrandName = t.Transport.BrandName,
}).ToList();
```

So I have data, and don't know how to convert it to `List<OwnerTransportTranspot>`.

Comment: I'm a little confused about your problem, at the end of your query you call .ToList(), this converts your query to a list, but you ask hot to convert it to a list?

Comment: Yes I have list, but don't know how to convert or not convert (don't know how to explain my problem, because I am quite new in coding in c#, MVVM, EntityFramework ect..) List<OwnerTransportTransport> ListIWantToShowInForm = ownerTransportList; I got error

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<xxx.DataModels.OwnerTransport>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<xxx.DataModels.OwnerTransportTransport>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can actually do this:

```
List<OwnerTransportTransport> ListIWantToShow =
                        (from transport in dbContext.TransportOwner
                        select new OwnerTransportTransport()
                        {
                            ID = transport.ID,
                            TransportID = transport.TransportID,
                            BrandName = transport.Transport.BrandName,
                            ModelName = transport.Transport.ModelName
                        }).ToList();


public class OwnerTransportTransport
{
  public int OwnerTransportID { get; set; }
  public int TransportID { get; set; }
  public string Brand { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer!! Actually it works :) but I also need to include filtering ... so I'v tried where transport.OwnerID StartWith(someParam) and query tooks 23 s :(

Comment: @Songaila Maybe, but you're filtering in the database in the code above. In your `implementation`, you'll drag all records from the database and filter them in-memory (inside the `foreach`). You might notice the difference when you have a lot of records in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I created class:

```
public class OwnerTransportTransport
{
  public int OwnerTransportID { get; set; }
  public int TransportID { get; set; }
  public string Brand { get; set; }
  public string Model { get; set; }
}
```

And then finaly what I needed :)

```
var query = dbContext.TransportOwner.AsQueryable();
ListIWantToShow = new List<OwnerTransportTransport>();
foreach (var transport in query)
  {
    OwnerTransportTransport NewList = new OwnerTransportTransport
      {
        ID = transport.ID,
        TransportID = transport.TransportID,
        BrandName = transport.Transport.BrandName,
        ModelName = transport.Transport.ModelName
      };

        ListIWantToShow.Add(tranport);
   }
```

Comment: Check my answer for a Query-Style linq way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

According to user3185569 answer, I wrote this:

```
var query = DBContext.TransportOwner.AsQueryable()
.Where(st => st.OwnerID.StartsWith(someParam));

List<OwnerTransportTransport> ListIWantToShow = query.Select(transport => new OwnerTransportTransport()
                        {
                            ID = transport.ID,
                            TransportID = transport.TransportID,
                            BrandName = transport.Transport.BrandName,
                            ModelName = transport.Transport.ModelName

                        }).ToList();
```

I have no mistakes at least, but compearing this code to foreach, it tooks so long :( but this answer was what I needed! I will accept it